# Java deadlock with one lock

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock

I have two objects in different threads using the same byte buffer. They both have the following method:

```
synchronized(buffer)
{
    ...

    if (...)
        buffer.wait();

    ...

    buffer.notifyAll();

    ...
}
```

Both objects will never wait at the same time.
This can cause deadlock. How do I handle it?

EDIT:

These objects are implementations of piped input and output streams.

Method in piped output stream class:

```
@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
{
    synchronized(sink.buffer)
    {
        if (sink.writepos == sink.readpos && sink.writelap == (sink.readlap + 1))
        {
            try
            {
                sink.buffer.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
            }

            write(b, off, len);
            return;
        }

        int amount = Math.min(len, (sink.writepos < sink.readpos ? sink.readpos : sink.buffer.length) - sink.writepos);
        System.arraycopy(b, off, sink.buffer, sink.writepos, amount);
        sink.writepos += amount;

        if (sink.writepos == sink.buffer.length)
        {
            sink.writepos = 0;
            sink.writelap++;
        }

        if (amount < len)
            write(b, off + amount, len - amount);
        else
            sink.buffer.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Method in piped input stream class:

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
{
    synchronized(buffer)
    {
        if (readpos == writepos && readlap == writelap)
        {
            try
            {
                buffer.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
            }

            return read(b, off, len);
        }

        int amount = Math.min(len, (writepos > readpos ? writepos : buffer.length) - readpos);
        System.arraycopy(buffer, readpos, b, off, amount);
        readpos += amount;

        if (readpos == buffer.length)
        {
            readpos = 0;
            readlap++;
        }

        if (amount < len)
        {
            int next = read(b, off + amount, len - amount);
            return amount + next;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.notifyAll();
        }

        return amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know why you want these threads to wait to be able to properly answer this.

Comment: @Saposhiente I added the code of the methods.

Comment: Did you intend the methods to be recursive? Are you getting a stack exception? `write` calls `write`, probably indefinitely?

Comment: @SanjayManohar Yes, the methods are intended to be recursive. `write` isn't called indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inserted a copious amount of debugging `println` statements into your methods and ran them attempting to read a 20-letter array of the lowercase alphabet through a 8-byte buffer, and got the following output:

```
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 0 (20 chars)
Writer synchronized
Want to read 20 chars into                      at 0
Writing 8; now abcdefgh 
New writer lap
Continuing write
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 8 (12 chars)
Writer synchronized
Writer waiting.
Reader synchronized
Read 8 into abcdefgh
New read lap
Continuing read
Want to read 12 chars into abcdefgh             at 8
Reader synchronized
Reader waiting.
```

This reveals the source of your problem: When `write` or `read` makes only partial progress on writing or reading, it does not notify the other thread that they may now write more. Moving the `notifyAll()` statement to be immediately after the `writepos += amount` and `readpos += amount` produces success:

```
Want to read 20 chars into                      at 0
Reader synchronized
Reader waiting.
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 0 (20 chars)
Writer synchronized
Writing 8; now abcdefgh
Writer notifying buffer.
New writer lap
Continuing write
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 8 (12 chars)
Writer synchronized
Writer waiting.
Reader resumed
Want to read 20 chars into                      at 0
Reader synchronized
Read 8 into abcdefgh            
Reader notifying buffer.
New read lap
Continuing read
Want to read 12 chars into abcdefgh             at 8
Reader synchronized
Reader waiting.
Writer resumed
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 8 (12 chars)
Writer synchronized
Writing 8; now ijklmnop
Writer notifying buffer.
New writer lap
Continuing write
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 16 (4 chars)
Writer synchronized
Writer waiting.
Reader resumed
Want to read 12 chars into abcdefgh             at 8
Reader synchronized
Read 8 into abcdefghijklmnop    
Reader notifying buffer.
New read lap
Continuing read
Want to read 4 chars into abcdefghijklmnop     at 16
Reader synchronized
Reader waiting.
Writer resumed
Want to write abcdefghijklmnopqrst at 16 (4 chars)
Writer synchronized
Writing 4; now qrstmnop
Writer notifying buffer.
Write finished.
Reader resumed
Want to read 4 chars into abcdefghijklmnop     at 16
Reader synchronized
Read 4 into abcdefghijklmnopqrst
Reader notifying buffer.
Read finsihed.
Read 20 chars
Read abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

Answer (score 0):

You have then both waiting to be notified. Leaving no other threads to notify them, you can't have both wait at the same time. You must insure that the condition in the if statement cannot be true for both threads at the same time.